# How to use SQL MERGE to remove duplicates, and update data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing some house-keeping on duplicate data. I have different tables like `Recipes`, `Ingredients`, and `RecipeIngredients`.

In the `Ingredients` table, users have previously added multiple ingredients with the same name/title, e.g., "chicken" will appear many times instead of just one. I want to remove the duplicates but still keep a reference to the recipe.

I am trying to use `SQL MERGE` but it is deleting the wrong data, and I have starred myself blind on it. What am I doing wrong / it's probably just some quick fix??

When I run the code below, I get this table relation:

```
Chicken Recipe
Chicken

Burger Recipe
Salt, Pepper, Patty
```

But what I really want is:

```
Chicken Recipe
Chicken, Salt

Burger Recipe
Salt, Pepper, Patty
```

The MERGE statement deletes the "Salt" from `RecipeIngredient` instead of removing the duplicate. What am I doing wrong?

```
-- create table structure
CREATE TABLE #Recipes (
    Id int,
    Title nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #Ingredients (
    Id int,
    Title nvarchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #RecipeIngredients (
    Id int,
    Recipe_id int,
    Ingredient_id int
)

-- load data
INSERT INTO #Recipes (Id,Title) VALUES (1,'Chicken Recipe');
INSERT INTO #Recipes (Id,Title) VALUES (2,'Burger Recipe');

INSERT INTO #Ingredients (Id,Title) VALUES (1,'Chicken'); 
INSERT INTO #Ingredients (Id,Title) VALUES (2,'Chicken'); -- duplicate ingredient
INSERT INTO #Ingredients (Id,Title) VALUES (3,'Salt'); 
INSERT INTO #Ingredients (Id,Title) VALUES (4,'Pepper');
INSERT INTO #Ingredients (Id,Title) VALUES (5,'Patty');

INSERT INTO #RecipeIngredients (Id,Recipe_id,Ingredient_id) VALUES (1,1,2); -- chicken has chicken
INSERT INTO #RecipeIngredients (Id,Recipe_id,Ingredient_id) VALUES (2,1,3); -- chicken has salt

INSERT INTO #RecipeIngredients (Id,Recipe_id,Ingredient_id) VALUES (3,2,3); -- burger has salt
INSERT INTO #RecipeIngredients (Id,Recipe_id,Ingredient_id) VALUES (4,2,4); -- burger has pepper
INSERT INTO #RecipeIngredients (Id,Recipe_id,Ingredient_id) VALUES (5,2,5); -- burger has patty


-- try to clean up
MERGE #RecipeIngredients 
USING
(
    SELECT MAX(id) as MyId
    FROM #Ingredients
    GROUP BY Title
) NewIngredients ON #RecipeIngredients.Id = NewIngredients.MyId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET #RecipeIngredients.Ingredient_id = NewIngredients.MyId
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
GO

-- delete duplicate ingredients, i.e., that no longer has a value in table #RecipeIngredients
DELETE FROM #Ingredients WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Ingredient_Id FROM #RecipeIngredients)
  
 -- clean up
DROP TABLE #Recipes
DROP TABLE #Ingredients
DROP TABLE #RecipeIngredients
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first update all the duplicate IDs to the single ID and then do the cleanup.

I've changed the winning ID determination from `MAX` to `MIN` since it will leave and have the same value in case there was an insert inbetween (hopefully you increment IDs as identity). Or you may use `SNAPSHOT` isolation level to enforce the max (or `SERIALIZABLE` to stop producing more new duplicates during this transaction). Also the cleanup of `#Ingredients` table should not use `in` filter, because as of design it is ok to have unused ingredients and users do not want to lose their data. So I've deleted the duplicates in the same way with `MIN(id)`.

This is updated `MERGE` statement which sets `Ingredient_ID` to the single value

```
MERGE #RecipeIngredients as t
USING
(
    SELECT id, min(id) over(partition by title) as MaxId
    FROM #Ingredients
) as NewIngredients
  ON t.Ingredient_Id = NewIngredients.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t.Ingredient_id = NewIngredients.MaxId;
```

Then I remove the duplicates from the `#RecipeIngredients`:

```
/*Cleanup duplicates from RecipeIngredients*/
delete t from (
  select
    row_number() over(
      partition by
        Recipe_id,
        Ingredient_id

      order by
        id asc
    ) as rn
  from #RecipeIngredients
) as t
where rn > 1
```

And finally cleanup the deduplicated records in `#Ingredients` table:

```
delete t from (
  select
    id,
    min(id) over(partition by title) as minid
  from #Ingredients
) as t
where id <> minid
```

And all the code in the *db<>fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a20eb295f18f5c62ceffb5710dc68d8a)*

**UPD**
I've added the more robust way to do a cleanup:

- remove duplicates from `#Ingredients` table first
- capture the deleted records
- then update `Ingredient_Id` for that deleted IDs in the `#RecipeIngredients` table, purging the duplicates in it (that can be created after unification, I do not know if it is the case) with `MERGE` statement.

Here's the new code and *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7272ae34992dc5d72f6101542a0cf5f)* for it. Also I've added anothed duplicated ingredient in `#Ingredients` table and another ingredient with different `Ingredient_Id` in `#RecipeIngredients` table (to show the `MERGE`'s deletion part).

```
/*Declare the table for unified ingredients*/
declare @deletedIngredients table (
  id int,
  unifiedId int
);

/*Cleanup of duplicate ingredients and
  catch the deleted records with the corresponding unified Id
*/
with i_del as (
  /*Leave only the first (by ID) record with the same name*/
  select id, min(id) over(partition by title) as unifiedId
  from #Ingredients
)
delete from i
  /*Catch the deleted records and corresponding unified Ids*/
  output
    deleted.id,
    i_del.unifiedId

  into @deletedIngredients

from #Ingredients as i
  join i_del
    on i.id = i_del.id
/*Remove only duplicates where Id is not equal to the master record Id*/
where i.id <> i_del.unifiedId
;

/*Then do an update of IDs on the RecipeIngredients
  and delete the duplicates from it (that can be created during the unification of Ingredients_Id)
*/
merge into #RecipeIngredients as t
using (
  select
    ri.id,
    i.unifiedid,
    /*Number the rows per Receipe_Id and new Ingredient_Id*/
    row_number() over(
      partition by
        ri.Recipe_Id,
        i.unifiedId
      
      order by ri.id asc
    ) as rn
  from #RecipeIngredients as ri
    join @deletedIngredients as i
      on ri.Ingredient_Id = i.id
) as s
  on t.id = s.id
/*The first record should have the new unified id*/
when matched and s.rn = 1 then
  update set ingredient_id = s.unifiedId
/*And unintentionally created duplicate should be removed*/
when matched and s.rn > 1 then delete
;

commit;
```

Comment: This is perfect. I guess there is no way to `DELETE` stuff correctly in the actual `MERGE`statement?

Comment: @Sha It is possible, but it should be determined first, which record will be a duplicate, which will be master and which should be deleted. I'll try to change the query to use one statement for this

Comment: @Sha I've updated my answer with a new code that tracks the integrity of deleted records in `Ingredients` table. But you of course cannot delete from two tables with single merge.